# Don't reset line numbers using Poetry package

Tags: poetry

I would like line numbers to not reset when using `poetry` environment.

Consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{poetry}

\setcounter{poemlinenumsevery}{5}

\begin{document}

{\bf First}

\begin{poem}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit\\!

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit\\!
\end{poem}

{\bf Second}

\begin{poem}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit\\!

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit\\!
\end{poem}

\end{document}
```

Is there a way to make the line numbering continue counting even though you've started a new verse environment?

Comment: For some reasons I can't compile your code, or modifications to it. However, its manual Ch. 3.1 desribes how to use `verseline` , there as a standard `renewcommand` . Just simplify the example to your needs, i.e. delete `:\arabic{verseline}` from the example given.

Comment: This doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: Thanks. The other option would be to avoid putting reset ˋ\\!ˋ too early.

Comment: I stop using this package. I have found more bugs using the verse counter. (Specially if you count by fives (5,10,15...)

Answer (score 1):

Ask the package maintainer for the enhancement.

If I understand correctly, line numbering can be carried across `poem` environments with a helper counter and its associated code changes added to each `poem` beginning and end, but then the modulo function will need to be rewritten.

[image: poetry]

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{poetry}

%\setcounter{poemlinenumsevery}{5}

\newcount\oldpoemlineno%
\newcounter{oldpoemline}%



\begin{document}

\textbf{First}

\begin{poem}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit\\!

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit\\?
\setcounter{oldpoemline}{\the\poemlineno}%
\end{poem}

\textbf{Second}

\begin{poem}*%
\setcounter{poemline}{\theoldpoemline}%
\poemlineno=\thepoemline%
\ifnum\poemlineno=1\poemlineno=\thepoemline\*\fi%
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit\\!

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit\\?
\setcounter{oldpoemline}{\the\poemlineno}%
\end{poem}


\textbf{Third}

\begin{poem}*%
\setcounter{poemline}{\theoldpoemline}%
\poemlineno=\thepoemline%
\ifnum\poemlineno=1\poemlineno=\thepoemline\*\fi%
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit\\!

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit\\?
\setcounter{oldpoemline}{\the\poemlineno}%
\end{poem}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But it doesn't work with \setcounter{poemlinenumsevery}{5}. I definitely stop using this package. I come back to 'verse'.

Comment: To use `poemlinenumsevery` with overall lines means completely re-writing the modulo function. It is not complicated, but a large coding change; and any hack will last only to the next version. Ask the package maintainer to make it part of the package.